# Unresolved reference: toUInt - Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, agora.io

I am getting compilation failed error for agora_rtc_engine plugin in Android Studio. Any hints to fix this?

````
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /Users/kshetty/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (9, 18): Unresolved reference: toUInt
e: /Users/kshetty/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (62, 18): Unresolved reference: toUInt
e: /Users/kshetty/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (102, 18): Unresolved reference: toUInt
e: /Users/kshetty/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (120, 18): Unresolved reference: toUInt ```
````

Answer (score 3):

This worked after setting kotlin_version version:
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'